# Does MongoDb C# driver works with LINQ and dynamic documents?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am wondering if I can even use LINQ on mongo documents that are not mapped and are fully dynamic. Reason for this is that I have ITEM aggrigator that holds unknown keys and values. This is only reason why I picked no-sql solution in the first place because EAV+SQL seems slow and overkill.

I inserted over 1m documents into my `test` collection that has `one` to `ten` fields with random data in it. Now I'm trying to get it back and using native Mongo queries it works, of course. Not so much using LINQ. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Error**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

**Code**

```
private static List<BsonDocument> Get(string query)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var db = server.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = db.GetCollection("items");
    var collectionQuery = collection.AsQueryable();
    
    var result = collection.Find(Query.EQ("Six", 7962)).ToList(); // THIS WORKS
    //var result = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x["Six"] == 7962).ToList(); // ERROR

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver does not currently support dynamic types. Here's the jira ticket for it:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-539

There's also an an interesting post about some possible workaround:
http://roysvork.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/using-linq-to-query-loosely-typed-data-in-mongodb/

Comment: Works perfectly fine with this guys fork and guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like version 1.10.0 of the driver supports dynamic documents in LINQ queries. That is, I have been able to execute queries like this:

```
        var collection = database.GetCollection("items");
        var query =
            from e in collection.AsQueryable()
            where e["string_property"] == "a_value"
            select e;

        foreach (var c in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c["another_property"]);
        }
```

The official documentation [C# Driver LINQ Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-linq-tutorial) only seems to include examples that use domain objects and is based on version 1.8.

The above code works in 1.10.0. I have not been able to ascertain when exactly support for the above code was added to the driver.